# angularjs - Avoid losing focus in input when selecting from autocomplete

Tags: angularjs, autocomplete, angularjs-directive

I have an input field with jquery autocomplete and another directive on it.

When the input field is losing focus a function is being called to perform some update using the value.

My problem is that when selecting a value from the autocomplete list using the mouse the input field is losing focus causing the value to save.

To avoid that behavior i changed the autocomplete directive to set the focus back to the input field after selection. The blur directive is checking for blur only after rendering

```
elm.bind('blur', function() { 
  // Wait for DOM to finish rendering
  $timeout(function() {
    if ( !$(elm).is(":focus")){
      scope.update();
      scope.check_dirty();
    }
  },0);
});
```

But it dosen't seem to work.
When reaching this function the `activeElement` is the body.

[PLUNKER example](http://plnkr.co/edit/RCZL8FYjAzZkGKp2X37H?p=preview)

Appreciate any help with this.

Comment: Had a quick play with the Plunker and it seemed that if you set the timeout value to 100ms or greater, things will work as you want. (Though I think the use of `$timeout` in this context is a bit hacky)

Comment: You right it does. But this is pretty much as ugly as it can get. You know of any other way to do that without hard coding a constant timeout ?

Comment: @haki: I don't really get what you are trying to achieve with the various functions and event-listeners, but I feel that you are overcomplicating things. Have you looked into how to utilize the various properties and functions of the `ngModelController` (it's quite powerful).

Comment: @ExpertSystem - It's you average auto-complete field that updates the value on Enter and blur. I've actually encountered several `ngModelController` oddities along the way (for example, having to `$render` after `$setViewValue` etc.). My only problem at the moment is selecting from the auto-complete list using the mouse.

Comment: @haki: Like I said, I don't really understand what you are trying to achieve with all those event-listenrs and timeouts (so I might be wrong). It just seems to comlicated. (BTW, what's "odd" about having to render a $viewValue ?)

Comment: If you have one directive setting the view value using a an `ngModelCtrl` you would expect another directive watching the value to trigger ? common sense. but no - according to the docs `$setViewValue` does not trigger `$digest` hence all the `$apply`s. Now, after setting using `$apply` the watch is fired but you still get the previous value - so you `$render`, and it goes on... This is a chronic of an over complicated code for a relatively simple task.

Comment: @haki: Have you looked into `$formatters` and `$parsers` ?

Comment: Thanks, I have. The root issue here is that the value is not updating and since both formatting and parsing act on the value - they wont have much effect in this case.

Comment: @haki: `$formatters` act on the `modelValue` and `$parsers` act on the `viewValue`. On of both must change (either rogrammatically or through user interaction).